# Prove that $d(\exp)_{X}(\mathfrak{h}_{H})=d(L_{\exp(X)})_{1}(\mathfrak{h}_{H})$ for all $X \in U$

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

Let $H$ be a closed subgroup of a Lie group $G$ and consider $\mathfrak{h}_{H}=\{X \in \mathfrak{g}:\exp(tX) \in H,~(\forall t \in \mathbb{R})\}$. Define $\psi: \mathfrak{h}_{H} \times \mathfrak{h}_{H}^\perp \to G$ by $\psi(X,Y)=\exp(X)\exp(Y)=\rho(\exp(X),\exp(Y))=\rho(\eta(X,Y))$, where $\eta(X,Y)=(\exp(X),\exp(Y))$.  Then, $\psi$ is differentiable and
\begin{eqnarray}
d(\psi)_{(0,0)}(A,B)&=& d(\rho)_{\eta(0,0)}\circ d(\eta)_{(0,0)}(A,B)\\
&=& d(\rho)_{\eta(0,0)}(d(\eta \circ i_{\exp(0)}^{1})_0 A+d(\eta \circ i_{\exp(0)}^{2})_0 B)\\
&=& d(\rho)_{\eta(0,0)}((d(\exp)_0(A),0)+(0,d(\exp)_0(B))\\
&=& d(\rho)_{\eta(0,0)}(A,B)\\
&=& d(\rho\circ i_{\exp(0)}^{1})_{\exp(0)}A+d(\rho\circ i_{\exp(0)}^{2})_{\exp(0)}B\\
&=&d(R_1)_{\exp(0)}A+d(L_1)_{\exp(0)}B\\
&=&A+B\cong(A,B)=\operatorname{Id}(A,B).
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore, from the Inverse Function Theorem, there exists open nbhd's $U \subset \mathfrak{h}_{H}$, $V \subset \mathfrak{h}_{H}^{\perp}$ and $W \in U(1)$ such that $\psi:U \times V \to W$ is a diffeomorphism.

I'm trying to prove that $d(\exp)_{X}(\mathfrak{h}_{H})=d(L_{\exp(X)})_{1}(\mathfrak{h}_{H})$ for all $X \in U$.

**My attempt:** As these spaces have the same dimension, it is sufficient prove that $d(L_{\exp(X)_1})(\mathfrak{h}_{H}) \subset d(\exp)_{X}(\mathfrak{h}_{H})$. Since the exponential map $\exp:U' \to W'$ is a diffeomorphism, we can suppose that $U \times V \subset U'$. I was trying to use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula, so that let $\beta(t)=\exp(X)\exp(tY)$, with $Y \in \mathfrak{h}_{H}$. $\color{red}{\text{If I could prove that}}$ $\color{red}{\beta(t) \in W}$ $\color{red}{\text{for all}}$ $\color{red}{t}$ $\color{red}{\text{sufficiently small}}$ then $\alpha(t)=\log(\beta(t))=X\ast tY$, with $X, tY \in \mathfrak{h}_{H}$ for all $t$ sufficiently small. From the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff we obtain $\alpha(t)=X \ast tY \in \mathfrak{h}_{H}$ (so that, $\alpha'(0) \in \mathfrak{h}_{H}$).

Thus, $d(\exp)_X(\alpha'(0))=d(\exp)_X \left( \frac{d}{dt} (\log(\beta(t)) \right)\big|_{t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\exp \circ \log \circ \beta\right)\big|_{t=0}=\beta'(0).$ Therefore, $\beta'(0) \in d(\exp)_X(\mathfrak{h}_{H})$. Note that, $d(L_{\exp(X)})_1(Y)=\frac{d}{dt}\exp(X)\exp(tY)\big|_{t=0}=\beta'(0) \in d(\exp)_X(\mathfrak{h}_{H})$, that is, $d(L_{\exp(X)})_1(d(\exp)_X(\mathfrak{h}_{H})) \subset d(\exp)_X(d(\exp)_X(\mathfrak{h}_{H}))$.

However, this statement in red does not seem to be valid, since $\beta(t) \in \exp(X)W$ for $t$ small. It would be even more interesting for me, if I had a proof that did not use the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. Perhaps, we have to shrink the neighborhood $U$, so that the statement in red is valid.

Since $W$ is a neighborhood of $1$, there exists $Z \in U(1)$ such that $Z^2 \subset W$ and $\widetilde{U}$ a neighborhood of $0 \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $\exp(\widetilde{U}) \subset Z$. Let $U \subset \mathfrak{h}_{H}$ and $V \subset \mathfrak{h}_{H}$ be open nbhd's such that $U \times V \subset \widetilde{U} \cap U'$. For all $Y \in U$, there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that $(tY,0) \in U \times V$ whenever $|t|<\varepsilon$. Thus, $\psi(tY,0)=\exp(tY)\in Z$ and $\psi(X,0)=\exp(X) \in Z$, i.e., $\exp(X)\exp(tY) \in Z^2 \subset W$.